# Why is this fluid baking taking so long?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I've made a simple scene (for learning purposes), but I've found the fluid sim baking process started taking a lot longer than what I expected (about 3 hours on one of my machines). This is for a 4s simulation with resolution 100.

Since it wasn't taking so long a while ago, I'm curious to know what setting I might have changed that made it so slow.

[image: Fluid domain settings]

Blender file: [image]

This is on Blender 2.79

Comment: I would think it would get more involved over time, what with liquid bouncing around all over the place, and adaptive domain (if you have that turned on).